# How can I get a message from a member then send it to a channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

If the member sends `randomize ${text}`, I want the bot to send `Your choice is ${text}`

```js
const collec = new Discord.MessageCollector(channelfilteroptions);

const text = collec.collect();

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message === `randomize ${text}`) {
        message.channel.send(`u send ${text}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: I highly recommend checking out the official guide for user input using `args`. View it [Here](http://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will only replace the first "randomize" found in your string, so if for some reason the user enters "randomize randomize", it will send "You sent randomize"

```
const text = message.content.replace('randomize', '');
message.channel.send(`You sent ${text});
```